# Expressing a linear map $\phi: \>{\mathbb R}^4\to{\mathbb R}^4$ in terms of a new base

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

In terms of the standard coordinates $x$, $y$, $z$, $t$ a linear map $\phi: \>{\mathbb R}^4\to{\mathbb R}^4$ appears as
$$\phi{(x,y,z,t)} = (t,x,y,z)\ .$$ Now we are given a new base $$R = \{ (1,0,1,0),(0,1,0,1),(0,1,1,0),(0,1,1,1) \}$$ of $\mathbb{R}^4$ and should find the matrix $M_R(\phi)$.

Is my thinking correct? As I understand  I need to find the matrix created by the linear transormation: 
$$
    \left( \begin{matrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
    1 & 0 & 0  & 0\\
    0& 1& 0  & 0\\
0& 0& 1  & 0\\
    \end{matrix} \right)
$$
then, solve 
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
  1&0&0&0&a\\
   0&1&1&1&b\\
 1&0&1&1&c\\
 0&1&0&1&d\\
\end{array}
\right] $$

by turning it to row echelon form to find out how the vector will look in the R basis. Is it the correct way to do a question like this?

Comment: Is the third vector in $R$ supposed to be $(1,1,1,0)$?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you proposing to replace $(a,b,c,d)$ with the each of the results of applying $\phi$ to each of the elements of $R$ In turn?

Comment: @amd yes, that was my initial idea

Comment: Good. That’s essentially what [Arthur’s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2903686/265466) describes.

Answer (score 2):

The most straight-forward way (as I see it) would be to follow this:

> The columns of the matrix representation of a linear transformation are the images of the basis vectors.

So, since the first basis vector in $R$ is $(1,0,1,0)$, the first column of $M_R(\phi)$ is $\phi(1, 0, 1, 0) = (0,1,0,1)$, but expressed using the basis $R$ rather than the standard basis. And so on.

Comment: So, the final matrix is this?:    \begin{matrix}
    0 & 1& 0 & 1\\
    1 & 0 & 0  & 0\\
    0& 1& 1 & 1\\
1& 0& 1 & 1\\
    \end{matrix}

Comment: @PufIniema Almost. But you have expressed the vectors in the standard basis. You have to express them in the basis $R$. So the first column should be $(0,1,0,0)^T$ because that's how you express $(0,1,0,1)_{\text{standard}}$ in the basis $R$.

Comment: I'm not able to post an image as a comment, so could you plase take a look at what I've written?

Comment: @PufIniema The first two columns are correct. The third and fourth are not. It is not the case that $(0,0,1,1)$ (the standard representation of $\phi(R_3)$) is equal to $1\cdot (0,1,1,0) + 2\cdot(0,1,1,1)$ (which is the standard representation of $(0,0,1,2)_R$). Instead, we have $(0,0,1,1) = (-1)\cdot (0,1,0,1) + (-1)\cdot(0,1,1,0) + 2\cdot(0,1,1,1)$, meaning that the $R$-representation of $(0,0,1,1)$ is $(0,-1, -1, 2)_R$, so _that_ is what the third column should be (transposed, of course). Smimilarily, the fourth column should be $(1, 0, -1, 1)^T$.

Comment: I found a basic arithmetic mistake in my calculations. After correcting it I got the same answer as you. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Indeed, this is what the OP had proposed doing.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix $P = \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$ transforms the basis $R$ to the canonical basis $E$.

Therefore

$$M_R(\phi) = P^{-1}M_E(\phi) P = \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -1 & -1 \\
 0 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thank you so much!